# Report Viewer is not in tool box for asp.net in visual studio 2015 Professional

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, rdlc

I want to create RDLC Report but could not find Reporting panel which contains Report Viewer in Toolbox.
Already installed Sql server data tool through control panel->add or remove program->modify VS15.

How to add Reporting Panel in toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by the following:

1. Get the nugget package for the Microsoft Report Viewer 2015
2. Add the report viewer to your toolbox.
   a. Right Click, then Choose Items...
   b. Browse to the dlls in the package.
3. Put the in control your webform.
   a. Drag the control from your toolbox onto the form.
   b. Set the Dock property to fill.
   c. Add the following code to YourForm.Designer.cs in the InitializeComponent() method.

   this.Controls.Add(reportViewer1);